# java classpath error using LibSVM programmatically within Weka

Tags: java, classpath, weka, libsvm

I'm trying to use LibSVM programmatically in Java, via the Weka wrapper written by El-Manzalawy, running on Windows 7. I've added `C:\Program Files (x86)\libsvm-3.12\java\libsvm.jar` to my `CLASSPATH` environmental variable. After adding that I can now use LibSVM via the Weka explorer user interface, but it still fails when I'm calling it in code (debugging in eclipse).

I try to create it using `Weka.core.Utils.forName`. This goes through to `LibSVM.java` which then calls the java method `Class.forName(...)`, passing CLASS_SVM as the param which is set to "libsvm.svm".

I've used `Weka.core.Utils.forName` to create others classifiers programmatically without problems.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Sicco - thanks for answer. I will try upgrading soon.

Comment: UPDATE: I've manually added LibSVM as an external java to my own project which fixes it (although I'm not too sure what *exactly* was happening, other than it not finding the jar...)

Comment: I have the same issue with Weka 3.7.11 . Everything works greate in Explorer and SimpleCLI, but the error appear when trying to specify   a training file! I think this is El-Manzalawy's fault because the exception is thrown from LibSVM.java . (It's seems crazy. LibSVM has problem to find itself!!!!)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to glue libsvm and weka in your java program using the answer posted here: [How to use LibSVM with Weka in my Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223982/how-to-use-libsvm-with-weka-in-my-java-code)

Answer (score 0):

Adding LibSVM is real easy when using Weka 3.7.6, because it allows you to install it via its package manager, either via [command line](http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager?#Command%20line%20package%20management) or [GUI](http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager?#GUI%20package%20manager). So I'd recommend using Weka 3.7.6.